# Adding shortcut(soft-link) of a directory to global PATH so that it can be accessed from everywhere

Tags: bash, ubuntu, path, sh, symlink

I'm trying to put all my symlinks in one directory (I'll call this symlinks directory). I've exported the path of that directory and put it in my `.bashrc` file. The symlinks to `executable applications` are running fine but I'm having hard time making `symlinks` for my directory. This is what I tried.

```
ln -s ~/mydir/ m
```

where `m` is supposed to be my symlink to `mydir` directory.

This works only when I'm inside `symlinks` directory. Trying `cd m` or even just `m` didn't work from outside that directory. I get:-

```
bash: cd: m: No such file or directory
```

Okay, so I thought maybe the `PATH` doesn't recognize `directory` paths. So I tried creating a `bash` script.

```
#!/bin/sh
cd ~/mydir/
```

Tried this, `m`...`permission denied`. Okay I thought and did `chmod +x m` to that file. And when I run that script like `m` then nothing. I tried `./m`, still nothing.

I'm close to losing my mind to do such a simple task.

Comment: I read your post a few times but still couldn't figure out what your problem is.

Comment: I'm trying to create a, let's call it shortcut, to a directory in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`PATH` is used to look for commands and I think a command ought to be a file or a symlink to a file.

So, `cd m` doesn't work as here the command is "cd" (not m). The lookup for "m" does not happen in PATH.

Just `m` does not work as the "m" found in PATH is a link to a directory and not a file. You can try creating another "m" which points to a file and put it in a directory later in the PATH and it will be recognized when you run just `m`.

The script you created does work, except that the `cd` now happens in a new shell and is lost at the end of the script. You can check this by putting an `ls` after the cd in your script.

There are a few ways to achieve what you want to do.

One option is to use the `CDPATH` variable. This is the search path for the `cd` command. Check `man bash` for details but basically, all you need to do is add your symlinks directory to CDPATH.

```
export CDPATH=~/symlinks:$CDPATH
cd m   ## will cd to linked directory
```

Alternatively, you can create aliases or functions and put it in your .bashrc or another file which you then source.

```
alias m="cd ~/mydir"

m() {
    cd ~/mydir
}
```

And now you can just type `m` to cd to mydir

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. Thank you!! Btw, I just did `alias m=cd ~/mydir` and it seems to work just fine. But +1 for other alternatives too.